# Why the two lines printed are not aligned in the script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Using below python script to build a idcard generator. Everything seems to work fine. But we have a strange problem.

The address in generated ID card are not aligned. It has enough space for the character. But it auto wrap lines.

[image]

I don't want "9室" to be printed in line 3. This only need two line for address info..

What's wrong with my code?

In case you don't understand chinese, I have translated all corresponding part to English. kindly refer below test info and script.

[image]

Below is my test data, please keep using the same address info if you run a test.

```
> Name： sponge baby     Gender: man  Nation: han
> 
> Birth Year:2005 Month ：6 Day：9
> 
> **Address:** 天上白玉京五楼十二城邦彩虹桥御花园88号999室
> 
> ID card Number: 18874155708596458
> 
> Issued By:the bottom of the sea 
> 
> Expiry Date: 2020-2030
```

Below is the key script. If you need full project code,here is the GITHub [link](https://github.com/airob0t/idcardgenerator).

```
# coding:utf-8
import os
import PIL.Image as PImage
from PIL import ImageFont, ImageDraw
import cv2
import numpy as np

try:
    from Tkinter import *
    from ttk import *
    from tkFileDialog import *
    from tkMessageBox import *
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter.ttk import *
    from tkinter.filedialog import *
    from tkinter.messagebox import *

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', None):
    base_dir = os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, 'usedres')
else:
    base_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'usedres')


def changeBackground(img, img_back, zoom_size, center):
    # Scale
    img = cv2.resize(img, zoom_size)
    rows, cols, channels = img.shape

    # convert hsv
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    # obtain mask
    # lower_blue = np.array([78, 43, 46])
    # upper_blue = np.array([110, 255, 255])
    diff = [5, 30, 30]
    gb = hsv[0, 0]
    lower_blue = np.array(gb - diff)
    upper_blue = np.array(gb + diff)
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)
    # cv2.imshow('Mask', mask)

    # Corrosion expansion
    erode = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=1)
    dilate = cv2.dilate(erode, None, iterations=1)

    # past
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            if dilate[i, j] == 0:  # 0 stand for Black point
                img_back[center[0] + i, center[1] + j] = img[i, j]  # Used to replace color ，for BGR

    return img_back


def paste(avatar, bg, zoom_size, center):
    avatar = cv2.resize(avatar, zoom_size)
    rows, cols, channels = avatar.shape
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            bg[center[0] + i, center[1] + j] = avatar[i, j]
    return bg


def generator():
    global ename, esex, enation, eyear, emon, eday, eaddr, eidn, eorg, elife, ebgvar
    name = ename.get()
    sex = esex.get()
    nation = enation.get()
    year = eyear.get()
    mon = emon.get()
    day = eday.get()
    org = eorg.get()
    life = elife.get()
    addr = eaddr.get()
    idn = eidn.get()

    fname = askopenfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(), title=u'choose head portrait')
    # print fname
    im = PImage.open(os.path.join(base_dir, 'empty.png'))
    avatar = PImage.open(fname)  # 500x670

    name_font = ImageFont.truetype(os.path.join(base_dir, 'hei.ttf'), 72)
    other_font = ImageFont.truetype(os.path.join(base_dir, 'hei.ttf'), 60)
    bdate_font = ImageFont.truetype(os.path.join(base_dir, 'fzhei.ttf'), 60)
    id_font = ImageFont.truetype(os.path.join(base_dir, 'ocrb10bt.ttf'), 72)

    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    draw.text((630, 690), name, fill=(0, 0, 0), font=name_font)
    draw.text((630, 840), sex, fill=(0, 0, 0), font=other_font)
    draw.text((1030, 840), nation, fill=(0, 0, 0), font=other_font)
    draw.text((630, 980), year, fill=(0, 0, 0), font=bdate_font)
    draw.text((950, 980), mon, fill=(0, 0, 0), font=bdate_font)
    draw.text((1150, 980), day, fill=(0, 0, 0), font=bdate_font)
    start = 0
    loc = 1120
    while start + 11 < len(addr):
        draw.text((630, loc), addr[start:start + 11], fill=(0, 0, 0), font=other_font)
        start += 11
        loc += 100
    draw.text((630, loc), addr[start:], fill=(0, 0, 0), font=other_font)
    draw.text((950, 1475), idn, fill=(0, 0, 0), font=id_font)
    draw.text((1050, 2750), org, fill=(0, 0, 0), font=other_font)
    draw.text((1050, 2895), life, fill=(0, 0, 0), font=other_font)

    if ebgvar.get():
        avatar = cv2.cvtColor(np.asarray(avatar), cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGRA)
        im = cv2.cvtColor(np.asarray(im), cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGRA)
        im = changeBackground(avatar, im, (500, 670), (690, 1500))
        im = PImage.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGBA))
    else:
        avatar = avatar.resize((500, 670))
        avatar = avatar.convert('RGBA')
        im.paste(avatar, (1500, 690), mask=avatar)
        # im = paste(avatar, im, (500, 670), (690, 1500))

    im.save('color.png')
    im.convert('L').save('bw.png')

    showinfo(u'succeed', u'file is generated in the directory,B&W bw.png and RGB color.png')


def run():
    global ename, esex, enation, eyear, emon, eday, eaddr, eidn, eorg, elife, ebgvar
    root = Tk()
    root.title(u'AIRobot ID Card generate')
    # root.geometry('640x480')
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    Label(root, text=u'Name:').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)
    ename = Entry(root, width=8)
    ename.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)
    Label(root, text=u'Gender:').grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)
    esex = Entry(root, width=8)
    esex.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)
    Label(root, text=u'Nation:').grid(row=0, column=4, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)
    enation = Entry(root, width=8)
    enation.grid(row=0, column=5, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)
    Label(root, text=u'Birth Year:').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)
    eyear = Entry(root, width=8)
    eyear.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)
    Label(root, text=u'Month:').grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)
    emon = Entry(root, width=8)
    emon.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)
    Label(root, text=u'Day:').grid(row=1, column=4, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)
    eday = Entry(root, width=8)
    eday.grid(row=1, column=5, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)
    Label(root, text=u'Address:').grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)
    eaddr = Entry(root, width=32)
    eaddr.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3, columnspan=5)
    Label(root, text=u'ID Number:').grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)
    eidn = Entry(root, width=32)
    eidn.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3, columnspan=5)
    Label(root, text=u'Issued By:').grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)
    eorg = Entry(root, width=32)
    eorg.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3, columnspan=5)
    Label(root, text=u'Expiry Date:').grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)
    elife = Entry(root, width=32)
    elife.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3, columnspan=5)
    Label(root, text=u'option:').grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)
    ebgvar = IntVar()
    ebg = Checkbutton(root, text=u'Auto Dig out Image', variable=ebgvar)
    ebg.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3, columnspan=5)
    Button(root, text=u'Generate', width=32, command=generator).grid(row=7, column=1, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3, columnspan=4)

    # root.iconbitmap(os.path.join(base_dir, 'ico.ico'))
    root.mainloop()
```

Any help will be highly appreciate.

Comment: Better use `Text` widget for the address so you can control how the address is split across lines.  Then use `draw.multiline_text(...)` to draw the address.

Answer (score 1):

The address is split into lines with this code:

```
while start + 11 < len(addr):
    draw.text((630, loc), addr[start:start + 11], fill=(0, 0, 0), font=other_font)
    start += 11
    loc += 100
```

The split is based on the number of characters, not based on the graphical text width. `彩虹桥御花园88号99` is 11 characters; the [Arabic numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals) are narrower than the Chinese characters, but the code does not account for this.

To fix this, you will need to do some kind of accounting for the actual text in `addr`; look at each character and decide how wide it is. I don't know offhand how to get this information from a TrueType font, but for your purposes you could try a simple heuristic e.g. "each Chinese character counts as 2x the width of a digit".